# Cannot uninstall a pip package

Tags: python, linux, pip, conda

I'm trying to uninstall `numpy`, but I get a permission error:

```
(base) tfovid@tfovid-t777s:~/codebase$ pip uninstall numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.5
Uninstalling numpy-1.19.5:
  Would remove:
    /usr/bin/f2py3
    /usr/bin/f2py3.9
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy-1.19.5.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 806, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/f2py3' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-mzc7w25e/f2py3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tfovid/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/tfovid/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 85, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "/home/tfovid/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 672, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/home/tfovid/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 386, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/home/tfovid/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 275, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/home/tfovid/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 324, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 821, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/f2py3'
```

I thought that sudo privileges would fix it but to no avail:

```
(base) tfovid@tfovid-t777s:~/codebase$ sudo pip uninstall numpy
[sudo] password for tfovid: 
Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.5
Not uninstalling numpy at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'numpy'. No files were found to uninstall.
(base) tfovid@tfovid-t777s:~/codebase$ sudo apt remove python-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-numpy
```

What could possibly the reason for this and how to solve it?

Comment: This is not a coding issue. SO is for programming problems. Please try asking at [askubntu.com](askubntu.com) or [superuser.com](superuser.com) or [serverfault.com](serverfault.com) and not here!

Comment: downvote was not from me ;) your Q is not for SO! If also needs details, that is why noone answered. Also you should not answer your own Q

Comment: Not arguing, asking: I am installing Pytest, and got an error. Attempting to remove 'click' and I'm getting the same error. Is not installing Pytest a programming thing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I had to specify Python **3**, so  `sudo apt remove python3-numpy` ended up working.